# phonegap and layouts

Tags: android, cordova, layout

I have an app that uses phonegap (cordova 2.1) which works by calling and index.html file and runs Javascript from that. I'm trying to implement a page flip animation I found on github here: https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl.

However, I'm unsure how to jump from my JS webview activity to the page curl activity.  Can I do this without a layout? If not how can I put the pagecurl layout on top of my JS activity so that it can still be seen in the background (so it looks like the page being turned).

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1835321/1321873 which discusses the HTML based solutions to page flip animation which, I think, will be better suited for Cordova implementation.